# How do I use relative links while developing a WordPress site on localhost?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wampserver

I'm developing a WordPress site. I am testing locally using a WAMP server. The front page of the website has a missing picture. When I click on any link in the front page, it goes "online" (leaves localhost).

What do I have to do, while developing, to stay on localhost and have all relative links?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import your website to localhost? if yes, then you might not have changed URLs of your website to localhost. You can do that by exporting SQL file of your website from phpmyadmin and then change all by any text editor and import it.  If its hardcoded for all links then you need to go to each link and change it manually.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set up a local subdomain for your local site. There is a link below on how to achieve this. It is a little bit complicated with WAMP, but not very hard to do. This will mean that your website URL could be website.dev rather than localhost/website, which means that relative URLs will work. I personally use [MAMP Pro](https://www.mamp.info/en/) rather than WAMP, because it allows you to easily set up and manage multiple local subdomains as well as some other handy features. Note that you would need to change your "siteurl" and "home" row values in the database table "wp_options" to the local subdomain if you want to do this on a local wordpress site you have already set up.

It is a bit hard to explain how to set up a local subdomain on here, so if this link ever breaks just google "setup local subdomains using Wamp".

http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/03/how-to-setup-local-subdomains-using-wampserver/